Cargo build using incorrect linker
I'm running into an issue trying to cross compile a simple "hello world".
For my use case, I need to build compile a simple application for both x86_64-apple-darwin and aarch64-apple-darwin inside of a linux container. I need it backed up into a binary that I can use with my existing swift code.
The issue I'm running into is that the toolchain executed when I run cargo build for a given target is not the toolchain for the target.
For example -
cargo build --release --target aarch64-apple-darwin
...
...
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1
       |
       = note: env -u IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET -u TVOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET -u XROS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET LC_ALL="C" PATH="/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/
...

I can see that it's using the stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu toolchain instead of aarch64-apple-darwin
Both targets and toolchains have been added in a prerequisite script
rustup target add x86_64-apple-darwin
rustup target add aarch64-apple-darwin
rustup install stable-x86_64-apple-darwin
rustup install stable-aarch64-apple-darwin

I have verified via rustup target list and rustup toolchain list that the aarch64 flavors are there, but they aren't being used.
I've tried just about everything that I can find to fix it, but nothing is working.
I tried setting the the toolchain in the build command itself cargo +stable-aarch64-apple-darwin build  --release --target aarch64-apple-darwin. I tried specifying the linker in my .cargo/cargo.toml. I've tried setting various rust flags.
Edit: I tried specifying the default tool chain, but noticed on the tool chain install I'm seeing the following
rustup install stable-aarch64-apple-darwin
error: DEPRECATED: future versions of rustup will require --force-non-host to install a non-host toolchain.
warning: toolchain 'stable-aarch64-apple-darwin' may not be able to run on this system.
warning: If you meant to build software to target that platform, perhaps try `rustup target add aarch64-apple-darwin` instead?
...
...
...
rustup default aarch64-apple-darwin
     error: toolchain 'aarch64-apple-darwin' is not installed


(note that I have already added the target for dustup)
Any thoughts on why this is (seemingly) refusing to use the correct linker?? Is it possible that I just can't use the Darwin linkers inside of a linux pod?
